# How to Split complex string to get filename and base64 string

Tags: c#, base64

Hi I have a string that comes from XML node, and I need to split the string and get the "filename=" value in one string and all the block of based64 in other to be able to decoded it and create the file.

I'm using Split("\n") but is creating a line for each line and this is not I need.Any Idea?

```
<Attachment>
      --boundaryfIudow==
      Content-Type: application/octet-stream;   name="IERL4-12-61.pdf"
      Content-Disposition: attachment; name="IERL4-12-61.pdf";
      filename="IERL4-12-61.pdf"
      Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

      JVBERi0xLjUNJeLjz9MNCjI4MzQgMCBvYmoNPDwvTGluZWFyaXplZCAxL0wgMTAxNTkyOS9PIDI4
      MzcvRSAxMDIyOTMvTiA0Mi9UIDEwMTUxMjkvSCBbIDU4MiA1MDZdPj4NZW5kb2JqDSAgICAgICAg
      DQoyODU1IDAgb2JqDTw8L0RlY29kZVBhcm1zPDwvQ29sdW1ucyA1L1ByZWRpY3RvciAxMj4+L0Zp
      bHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9JRFs8QTlCNjc4ODAwODkwODg0QjgyQURCRDk5N0U4OERERTY+PERD
      RDYyNDA0OTNDQUUyNDE5MjkwNzc4OEMyMUE1MEEyPl0vSW5kZXhbMjgzNCA3MF0vSW5mbyAyODMz
      IDAgUi9MZW5ndGggMTEwL1ByZXYgMTAxNTEzMC9Sb290IDI4MzUgMCBSL1NpemUgMjkwNC9UeXBl
      L1hSZWYvV1sxIDMgMV0+PnN0cmVhbQ0KaN5iYmRgEGBgYmBgMQCRDLtBJKMZmNwCIll3gkhmQbAI
      WA3LOjAJES8Gs0+ASUkQyTQJzJYDy64AkYaNQJKR6xGIrSIDNucVmBQFkv9LWBiYGBm4F4FtZ2Ac
      LKTAy0Hhkv8M3xVeAQQYAET0ENYNCmVuZHN0cmVhbQ1lbmRvYmoNc3RhcnR4cmVmDQowDQolJUVP
      Rg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg
      ICAgICAgICAgIA0KMjkwMyAwIG9iag08PC9DIDUzNS9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUvSSA1NTcv
      TGVuZ3RoIDQxMC9PIDUxOS9TIDQzMz4+c3RyZWFtDQpo3mJgYGBiYGA2Z2BhYODLYRBkQABBBmYG
      VqA4xwcGBgETZ0MGBgUk2b1/mCIbzigELuC7wX2DxYbVfvNGh0NSr/TEfzImhL4R/iPyiZG1tfvQ
      LkU/h2iOoBKmByJ7WNNZ9RlzHCccSN6QeENrmoAnZ0CbGVOdY6HClA43HgU3wZtMx4Am79RUzt0e
      mxd2txRI7o7dAhRid/aWkmV3vBQly9soN0PWxaqjVOCVFU+JxAujni8S7UE9h1e0B/ItdngVOAMo
      oXjFeaVbIpQASaz2Zg/jW50FJNbIJl2/kLvg0XW+jdntYSAicquJzK0GxowG1owGBgbRBrYGwQYO
      Bihi7mBoYOoAMTsYJCBiHkAcgWCCcAMrUAlLB4MGmM8CUkq70AGCDAZu+UJwBDEwSINFXgHZqQyf
      D7g8YEkQU+C2YRViusc4vUGLIa1B+2HNHuUHbilAVaKrlzZIBkxmrPRg+BlyXyiIIYCBv+HAA4ih
      3GoMjF1lQAYjMDmoAukiBr4rRhAbpqXDo72fgb8qF6KK4TNAgAEAW6qi8w0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDWVu
      ZG9iag0yODM1IDAgb2JqDTw8L0xhbmcoZW4tVVMpL01hcmtJbmZvPDwvTWFya2VkIHRydWU+Pi9N
      ZXRhZGF0YSAxNDEgMCBSL09wZW5BY3Rpb24gMjgzNiAwIFIvT3V0bGluZXMgMjg4MCAwIFIvUGFn
      --boundaryfIudow==--
    </Attachment>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go (src is your source string):

```
var split = src.Split('\n').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList();

var filename = split.First(p => p.StartsWith("filename="));
filename = filename.Substring(10, filename.Length - 11);

var base64 = split[split.Count - 2];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, But I'm getting one error "Message=Sequence contains no matching element" in this line var filename = split.First(p => p.StartsWith("filename="));     but the "filename=" exist ..

Comment: Then it doesn't get split properly. See in Debug what values you get from splitting your string. Here's my code: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/u3QBXwn9)

Comment: I'm getting this " filename=\"IERL4-12-61.pdf\"" in the specific line

Comment: Ah, so you got some whitespace characters there. No big deal, you just need to trim the split entries before doing anything on them. I updated my answer. Note that `.Length` changed to `.Count`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm learning a now... I'm getting the name correctly.. but I'm now getting all the base64 block code, just the first line ..

Comment: Come on man, I can't do your work for you. See how it gets split up and fix it.

Comment: Sorry I din't mean to look like that, Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the XMLNode, use it.
Parse it to an Element.

```
XmlElement attachment = (XmlElement)node; 
var filename = attachment.GetAttribute("filename").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It's not an attribute, it's plain text within the element.